# python 3 pyautogui.click() "blocked" by not active application

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, click, pyautogui

Im using python 3.7 and windows 10
I got this script:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click()
```

It runs fine on my computer untill i until i launch a specific program (program A), then it completely stop working. It does not only not work when this program (program A) is highlighted but also in every other program (program B, C, ..) that is currently running. Before program A is started my code works fine in the other programs (B ,C ,...).

I do not get any errors, the code still executes as expected but without actually doing a mouse click.

one thing worth noting is that if i use  pyautogui.moveTo(x,y) the mouse do still move.

Any ideas on why this is happening? and/or how I can work around / solve the problem ?

Note:
I have seen answers where the .click() function doesen't work within specific applications, but in my case it stops working within the entire os (any application) as long as Program A is running.

Note #2:
i have tried this on an other computer as-well, problem is the same.

Note #3:
I do run everything as an admin

Comment: How are you running the program while not in the window you use to run the program? And are you absolutely sure the mouse is not clicking?

Comment: putting `time.sleep(5)` gives me 5 sec to jump to any other program, And that is working when A is not running. Even if i do stay in the active console window no clicking is done if A is running. _(if I stay i the active console window and run the code while A is NOT running clicking is done, i can for example minimize the console window doing this)_